# Props not rendering in child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I am trying to pass an error message to child component but it is not rendering it. Hard coded message is displayed only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYSYz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnSJb.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXe8.png)

I tried passing an error message as props and display it but its not happening.

Comment: please put the code as text in the question. otherwise it wil be closed

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing from camelCase names to kebab-case because it's not allowed for DOM templates. Try like  ...MyComponent greeting-message="hello" /> and defineProps({
greeting-message: String
}).
Also you can look in [Vue Js Props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)

Comment: it's written in kebab case only

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this?

`<ErrorPage v-else :errorMessage="this page is not Loading"/>`

Comment: I tried but that didn;t work